# Присвоить фрэйму с динамически получаемым id - значение src

Tags: jquery

Ошибка во фрагменте присвоения значения src, понимаю что нельзя так делать, а как правильно это сделать знаний пока не хватает..
P.S. Необходимо использовать существующий фрэйм.

```html
<iframe id='' width="210" height="150" src='' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

      var sampleUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRMsJ12EpzA";
      var video_id = sampleUrl.split("v=")[1].substring(0, 11);
      var source = document.querySelector("iframe");
      source.id = video_id;
      var source_end = document.querySelector("iframe#id");
      source_end.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video_id;
    },
    false
  )
</script>
```

Comment: А в чём именно проблема?

Comment: @ Yuri Фрэйму с динамически присваеваемым id нужно присвоить по полученному id - src

Answer (score 2):

Используй тот же элемент.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var sampleUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRMsJ12EpzA";
    var video_id = sampleUrl.split("v=")[1].substring(0, 11);
    var source = document.querySelector("iframe");
    source.id = video_id;
    source.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video_id;
}, false);
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var youbeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRMsJ12EpzA",
      videoId = youbeUrl.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/, "$1"),
      iframeObj = document.querySelector("iframe");
      
  iframeObj.id = videoId;
      
  var newIframeObj = document.querySelector("iframe#" + videoId); // iframe#eRMsJ12EpzA
  
  newIframeObj.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId;
}, false)
```

```html
<iframe width="210" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: У Вас данный вариант работает?

Comment: @Dmitry, секунду, сейчас подшаманю. Погодите пару минут

Comment: @Dmitry, готово. Забыл id присвоить

Comment: Большое спасибо, кажется то что нужно!

Comment: @Dmitry, не за что